# How do oral probiotics reach vaginal mucosa?

Tags: probiotics

I have read online ([Vásquez et al. 2005](https://doi.org/10.1080/08910600510031376)) that oral lactobacillus is more effective than local suppository in the treatment of recurrent vaginal candidiasis.

So how can an oral probiotic which has lactobacillus reach the vaginal mucosa through the Gastro Intestinal Tract?

I know bacteria is not absorbed so I can not figure the mechanism of action.

### References

Vásquez, A., Ahrné, S., Jeppsson, B., & Molin, G. (2005). Oral administration of Lactobacillus and Bifidobacterium strains of intestinal and vaginal origin to healthy human females: re-isolation from faeces and vagina. Microbial ecology in health and disease, 17(1), 15-20. https://doi.org/10.1080/08910600510031376

Comment: There is something in the "GIT"  that's very close to the vagina, and from which the vagina may be contaminated in susceptible populations/certain conditions. If the offending pathogen is eliminated from the "GIT", it's less likely to reinfect the vagina, no? A more complete answer is more complex, but this factor affecting vaginal microbiota should not be overlooked.